# Is it possible to study applied and pure math subjects on single PhD program?

Tags: phd, mathematics, united-states

I'm aiming to study in USA mathematics  PhD program .

I love Pure mathematics  very much. I can't live without it but Applied math is more promised and demanded.

Could I study Pure mathematics and applied mathematics subjects together in Single PhD program?

Comment: Yes. Mathematics is not binary. It lies on a spectrum (no pun intended). There are plenty of fields that have major theoretical and computational aspects.

Comment: More experienced people will chip in, but what about quantum computing? A lot of phyicists are happy there, it must mean the *applied* mathematics part is quite relevant :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with a bachelors and if you choose your university carefully, then probably yes, it is possible. Harder if you start with a masters since there is less time.

Suppose, however, that the university has a single math department with both pure and applied faculty. (Harder otherwise)

Then, since the first years are normally advanced coursework leading to comprehensive/qualifying exams, there is the possibility to take a few additional courses of your choice.

At some point, however, possibly early, you will probably need to make a choice of an advisor and a specific area of specialization. From that point you will have fewer options (again, time will be an issue).

An alternative, however, is to focus on one from the start and then, once you have a degree and some experience, branch out. It is probably easier to move from pure to applied than the other direction, however. This is just because of the way pure mathematicians think about problem solving. When faced with a "real world" problem they have a lot of tools to bring to the game.

But you may be making a mistake in assuming that applied math is more in demand. I'd guess the opposite is true in academia and even less true than you might think in industry. I don't have statistics, though.

Comment: applied mathematics is much more profitable. Can I work for applied mathematics jobs with Pure Mathematics PhD education?

Comment: @JohnNash: I think you are overestimating the relation between what you do in your PhD and what you might do in an industry job afterwards. I've seen "pure" mathematicians working e.g. as software developers, or in consulting, or as development engineers for electrical engineering projects. Many of those jobs can be done by anybody who (a) is really interested in the job and (b) has a solid background in mathematics and programming - no matter whether they have a PhD in, say, algebraic geometry, or numerical analysis, or theoretical physics, or a branch of computer science. [...]

Comment: [...] This is not to say that a PhD in mathematics would be useless. Apart from certain approaches to solving problems which you learn during a PhD in mathematics, it can also happen on some occassions that using a solid amount of mathematics will indeed help you solve a specific problem. But it's extremely unlikely that the specific piece of maths that you'll happen to need is known to you precisely and solely because of the choice of your PhD topic.